# Azure virtual network service endpoints - which resources can act as a client?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

In the context of virtual network service endpoints, the documentation states:

> Endpoints work with any type of compute instances running within that subnet.

What exactly is meant by *compute instances*? It's clear that this includes virtual machine instances, but does this also include e.g. an app service with vnet integration? How about Azure functions? What other services/azure resources are able to talk to service endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you already named a few there. Without completeness:

- VMs
- AKS (which is VMs...)
- App Services and Functions (same platform)
- Container Instances
- Databricks

Answer (score 0):

@silent has already listed the services, I would like to add that most of the services make use of the compute instances in some form or the other.

Clients that are deployed inside of a subnet or are connected/integrated with a subnet can connection to Service Endpoint enabled destinations.

You could also add **App Service Environment** to the list. Though its App Services, it is a different offering compared to regular App Services.